# Codeigniter and ajax query involving one more view

Tags: jquery, ajax, view, codeigniter-2

I am trying to call an AJAX output involving classic MVC scheme. 
My jquery method is communicating with controller and I can catch the variables sent by the jquery. What ever is being printed in the contoller is correctly showing back in jquery alert  box ... 
However I can not get to my jquery method anything from the view called by the controller which is supposed to generate the ajax output. 
I ma using a codeigniter 2.

This is the calling jquery method in my view:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/get_promos/",
        cache: false,
        data: {promos_id: JSON.stringify(jsonObj)},
        success: function(data){
               alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });
```

Here is my controller :

```
public function get_promos(){ 
        if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request()) 
        {
            exit('No direct script access allowed');
        }
        else {
            $data['promos_id'] = $this->input->post('promos_id');
            echo $data['promos_id'];
            $this->view->load('list_promo_estab_ajax', $data);
        }
    }
```

And here is my view 'list_promo_estab_ajax.php' which I am trying to load in the above controller, but nothing gets back to my jquery method :

```
<?php 
echo 'basic blah';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in view loader.

I wrote:

```
$this->view->load('list_promo_estab_ajax', $data);
```

While the correct syntax should be :

```
 $this->load->view('list_promo_estab_ajax', $data);
```